# Limit of the sequence: $\frac{k(k+1)}{(k+1)^2-qk^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am stuck on the proof of this limit:
given the sequence:
$$S(k,q)=\frac{k(k+1)}{(k+1)^2-qk^2}$$
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}S(k,q)=-\frac{1}{q-1}$$
How can I prove this limit?

Comment: Divide all terms by $k^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Expand the products and squares in the nominator and denominator and multiply both with $1/k^2$. As $k\to\infty$, all the terms that look like $1/k^i$ vanish and you are done. This is the standard trick to calculate limits of quotients of polynomials.

Comment: The reason that this works is because, when you multiply top and bottom by $\frac{1}{k^2}$, both the top and bottom have finite limits. The limit of a quotient is equal to the quotient of the limits provided that the limit of denominator and numerator are both finite and non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{k(k+1)}{(k+1)^2-q.k^2}=\frac{1}{\frac{k+1}{k}-q.\frac{k}{k+1}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{k}-q.\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{k}}}$